# How can I output my textfile to uppercase hash?

Tags: terminal

I have a large text file consisting of two columns that I'm looking to convert to uppercase hash. The text file is too large for me to open up in Excel (over 1 million rows), and I was trying to do this through command line if possible.

Hoping for column B to just be hashed, but fine if rest of the file is hashed.

Edit: Essentially, I have a text file with column A as first name and column B of Email addresses. I was hoping to [use something like this](http://albertech.blogspot.com/2011/08/generate-sha1-hash-from-command-line-in.html) to convert column B into uppercase hash, so that it is encrypted to transfer where someone else can convert it back.

I saw this code but wasn't sure where I'd specify the file name and column I wanted to convert to hash

```
echo -n password | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}'

5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
```

Comment: your question is somehow ambiguous that I could not find out what exactly you meant. Please leave an example to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: What do you mean by uppercase hash? Do you want to convert all the letters into upper cases?

Comment: Essentially, I have a text file with column A as first name and column B of Email addresses. I was hoping to [use something like this](http://albertech.blogspot.com/2011/08/generate-sha1-hash-from-command-line-in.html) to convert column B into uppercase hash, so that it is encrypted to transfer where someone else can convert it back.

Comment: you can do something like this: `cat filename.csv | cut -d' ' -f2 | sha1sum` or `cat filename.csv | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | sha1sum`
It is prefered to convert your file to CSV format if it is not. It can be helpful to overcome possible problems with other formats like XSLT and others.

Comment: @epcpu I just tried that out and it looks okay, but when I opened the file, nothing was changed

Comment: you can redirect the output to a file using `... sha1sum > newfileName`

Comment: @epcpu thanks for your help. it looks like it output a single hash. that doesn't contain all the other rows, does it? or do I need to repeat and echo each row?

Comment: did you cat the input file? cat reads all the lines one by one. check if the output file has any empty lines. I wonder if the print $2 does not print the true index of the split input string.